# User gets internaly loged in, but UI does not change

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

So I have a problem with my app's login. When a user enters correct login data, he gets recognized on the firebase console, debug console also shows the user now exists, but the screen (which is controlled by StreamBuilder) does not change.

```
home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
                  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> userSnapshot) {
                    if (userSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return LoadingSpinner();
                    }
                    if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
                      return MainScreen();
                    }
                    return AuthScreen();
                  }),
//.............

void authUser(String email, String password, bool isLogin,
      String username) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    UserCredential userCreadencial;
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

      if (isLogin == false) {
        userCreadencial = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } else {
        userCreadencial = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      }
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users_info')
          .orderBy(userCreadencial.user!.uid, descending: true);
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users_info')
          .doc(userCreadencial.user!.uid)
          .set({
        'email': userCreadencial.user!.email,
        'username': username,
      });

      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
```

Debug console log:

> W/System  (14293): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value
> was null. 2 I/System.out(14293): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled
> false D/FirebaseAuth(14293): Notifying id token listeners about user (
> 55epaBG5sGYJ7YWq1QZosJqrajT2 ).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a simillar problem recently. I have found a workaround for this problem. You can use "whenComplete" function & a condition if the current user uid is not empty to navigate to the route after the signIn or login is successful. This is how your code might look like:

```
void authUser(String email, String password, bool isLogin,
  String username) async {
setState(() {
  isLoading = true;
});
UserCredential userCreadencial;
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

//to get current uid
String get currentUserUid => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid ?? '';

  if (isLogin == false) {
    //add whenComplete & check if the current uid is not empty.
    userCreadencial = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    ).whenComplete(
          () => currentUserUid.isNotEmpty
            ? Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MainScreen(),
            ),
            (route) => false,
          ):null,
        );;
  } else {
    //add whenComplete.
    userCreadencial = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    ).whenComplete(
          () => currentUserUid.isNotEmpty
            ? Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => MainScreen(),
            ),
            (route) => false,
          ): null,
        );;
  }
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users_info')
      .orderBy(userCreadencial.user!.uid, descending: true);
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users_info')
      .doc(userCreadencial.user!.uid)
      .set({
    'email': userCreadencial.user!.email,
    'username': username,
  });

  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
```

*you should also wrap your signIn and createUser function with try catch blocks*